# File Folder Permissions

Tags: directory, permissions, subinacl

How do we extract existing acl/folders permissions and make into readonly for the existing set of users; excluding administrators and system accounts.  for example c:\data and it's subfolders different users are having modify/full permissions which include admins and SYSTEM account.  I want to be able to just take the user and convert into read.

Regards.

So far I tried with subinacl to export it the acls to a file and remove/change the access mask for the users to read and do a playfile.  But now I stuck with a folder which has huge number of subfolders (the log file is around 4 gb).   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions.